# How do I change a string into a password?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have:

```
$('#pass').on('keyup keydown', function() { //the password input
    $('#pass-result').text( $(this).val() ); //the input's bullet's, not string value
});
```

The text value of the password is printed as the input's string. How do I convert it to the password's masqueraded bullet form (•)?

Comment: Do you actually need the string of dots, or are you just looking for dots to appear in the field when text is entered in it?

Comment: `<input type="password">`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Post a complete code example please.

Comment: @APerson I need a string of dots.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for dots to appear in the field when text is typed in it, you should use `<input type="password">` instead of `<input type="text">`:

```html
<input type="password" id="pass" />
```

which you would get the text from with `$("pass").val()`.

It looks like you want a string of dots instead. To accomplish this, use:

```
var dots = Array($("pass").val().length + 1).join("•");
```

To explain:

- `$("pass").val()` gets the text
- `$("pass").val().length` gets the length of that
- `Array($("pass").val().length + 1)` gets a new Array whose length is 1 more than the length of the password text
- `Array($("pass").val().length + 1).join("•")` returns each element of the Array with a dot inserted between each - which is why we needed 1 extra, otherwise we would get a fencepost error.

Comment: I am already using a password input. I don't want `$("pass").val()` to be the user's input, I want it to be bullets.

Comment: then $("pass").val().length and add that many bullets to a string?

Answer (score 0):

According to the fact that you only want to parse a string of dots . what you gonna do is (IF YOU USE 2 INPUTS!)

```
    function getKeyCode(event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        return event.keyCode;
     }

$('#pass').on('keyup', function(e) { //the password input
    if (getKeyCode(e) == 8) {
        $('#pass-result').val($('#pass-result').val().slice(0,-1) );
    }
    else {
        $('#pass-result').val($('#pass-result').val() + '•');
    }
});
```

didnt test the code though. but it should add a  • to the `#pass-result` on ever key-down in the `#pass` field. it doesnt remove any on backspace though..

http://jsfiddle.net/7810squo/

if you wanna do it with a `<span>` you need to use `.html()`

```
    function getKeyCode(event) {
       event = event || window.event;
        return event.keyCode;
    }

$('#pass').on('keyup', function(e) { //the password input
    if (getKeyCode(e) == 8) {
        $('#pass-result').html($('#pass-result').html().slice(0,-1) );
    }
    else {
        $('#pass-result').html($('#pass-result').html() + '•');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u9kdeewd/

EDIT: updated code and provided jsFiddle link

Comment: ill make myself a fiddle and fix it real quick. gimme.. like.. 10minutes